# How to get Date from my JSpinner?

Tags: java, swing, date, jspinner

this is the code of the Spinner

```
Hini = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.MINUTE);
JSpinner Hini = new JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(Hini, "hh:mm a");
de.getTextField().setEditable( true );
Hini.setEditor(de);
```

And this is how i want it to get the values, but it always shows "00:00"

```
    `SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH/mm");
     String spinnerValue = formater.format(Hini.getValue());
     System.out.println(spinnerValue);`
```

I also tried this but it always showed the actual time, not the one I picked

```
Hini = new JSpinner(sm);
de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(Hini, "hh:mm a");
de.getTextField().setEditable( false );
Hini.setEditor(de);
System.out.println("Spinner:      "+de.getFormat().format(Hini.getValue()));
```

Comment: You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be creating two instance of the `JSpinner`

```
// Instance(?) field here...
Hini = new javax.swing.JSpinner();
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.MINUTE);
// Local field here
JSpinner Hini = new JSpinner(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor de = new JSpinner.DateEditor(Hini, "hh:mm a");
de.getTextField().setEditable( true );
Hini.setEditor(de);
```

So I can only guess that the local field is what is getting added to the UI and the instance field is been ignored, meaning that whatever the user enters into the field isn't been set to the instance field.

Drop the creation of the second field and replace it with `Hini.setModel(sm);`

Instead of formatting the value directly from the `JSpinner`, you should simply get a reference to the `Date` value and only format when you really need to.  This provides you with a more flexible solution

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked i didn't realize I was creating two instances, you are my hero

Comment: Hero? Hmm, I must be doing something wrong ;) Glad it helpd ;)