# How to get date value from jspinner

Tags: java, date, return, jspinner

I have searched for a while, and I can't get the value from the jspinner. Here is my code :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currentYear;
        currentYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        SpinnerModel model =
            new SpinnerNumberModel(currentYear, //initial value
                                   currentYear - 100, //min
                                   currentYear + 100, //max
                                   1);                //step


        Date initDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, -100);
        Date earliestDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 200);
        Date latestDate = calendar.getTime();
        model = new SpinnerDateModel(initDate,
                                    earliestDate,
                                    latestDate,
                                    Calendar.YEAR);
        final JSpinner spinnerDateNais = new JSpinner(model);
        spinnerDateNais.setEditor(new JSpinner.DateEditor(spinnerDateNais, "dd/MM/yyyy"));

        Date dateTest;
        spinnerDateNais.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener(){
                    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                              System.out.println((Date)spinnerDateNais.getValue());//Here I need to get the values
                }
                });

        panneauFormulaire.add(spinnerDateNais);
```

So I need to get the value of date jspinner and use it. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Date from my JSpinner?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162285/how-to-get-date-from-my-jspinner). **Please search StackOverflow** before posting. This topic has been addressed *many* times already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Code for initialize JSpinner

```
JSpinner DateSpinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerDateModel()); 
JSpinner.DateEditor dateEditor = new JSpinner.DateEditor(DateSpinner, "E dd/MM/yyyy"); 
DateSpinner.setEditor(dateEditor);
```

Code for get LocalDate from JSpinner

```
Date date = (Date) DateSpinner.getValue();   
LocalDate localDate = DateConverter.asLocalDate(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  **spinnerDateNais.getValue()** method. It will give you the value from JSpinner.